# Laravel | Unable to get array of strings searched from the database

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

**What is the ultimate use-case ?**

My mobile App is going to send a query for `https://example.com/public/api/classifiedsearch?search=name%3Aorange+apples+grapes+onions`

& I'd expect the results to include data from the `products` table with `name` containing the term in the search strings above. The problem that I'm facing is that, i don't get any results matched at all. I have confirmed by printing that `$terms` (referred below) is indeed able to capture the values from search as an array & the for loop is working the number of times equalent to the number of words in search string. But no results returned. Any hint/suggestions to why isn't it mapping ????

Here's what i have done in my `APIcontroller` for `classifiedsearch`

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    try{
       $queryString = $request->input('search',null);
         $terms = explode(" ",$queryString);
    
    // print_r($terms);
              
      if ( !empty( $request->query('search')))
      {
                   
        $products = Product::whereHas('store', function ($query) use ($terms) 
               {
                    foreach ($terms as $term) 
                    {
                     //    print_r("CHECKING FOR $term");
                    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
                    
                    }
               })->get();
          
      }
            
      else 
      {       
           $products = $this->productRepository->all(); 
      }
           
    } catch (RepositoryException $e) {
        return $this->sendError($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $this->sendResponse($products->toArray(), 'Products retrieved successfully');
}
```

**Output :**

```
{"success":true,"data":[],"message":"Products retrieved successfully"}
```

Can someone please help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see what you want to achieve, can u try this :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
  try{
    $queryString = $request->input('search',null);
    $terms = explode(" ", $queryString);
            
    if(!empty($request->query('search'))){       
      $products = Product::whereHas('store', function ($query) use ($terms){
        foreach ($terms as $key => $term){
          //if first loop, use Where, if multiple then add orWhere to current query
          if($key == 0)
            $query = $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$term}%");
          else
            $query = $query->orWhere('name', 'like', "%{$term}%");
        }
        return $query;
      })->get();
    }else{       
       $products = $this->productRepository->all(); 
    } 
  }catch(RepositoryException $e){
    return $this->sendError($e->getMessage());
  }
  return $this->sendResponse($products->toArray(), 'Products retrieved successfully');
}
```

Comment: Where in the heaven did you come from man ???!!! This is exactly what i needed & it works like a magic. Even the vulnerable solution that i've been relying did have some kickbacks in terms of my use-case. You just made a team happy today!!!! & yes THIS IS THE SOLUTION TO THE QUESTION THAT I've BEEN RUNNING AROUND WITH!!!!  Others who posted answers didn't bother to fully understand the ultimate use-case...Thank you so much Sir! Cheers

Comment: you're welcome @AdrianKarr, im from planet called Earth hahaha

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the code is that the `search` parameter is being prefixed by the value 'name:' [in HTML %3A decodes into a colon : ]

search=**name%3A**orange+apples+grapes+onions

So this line: `$terms = explode(" ",$queryString);`

Will actually return an array as:

`['name:orange', 'apples', 'grapes', 'onions']`

Since your query of terms is using an implicit `AND` for the terms:

`$query->where`

It's likely never going to return a result, since its unlikely to have a value in the database prefixed with  "name:".

I would suggest to remove "name%3" from the GET query string in your frontend client code.

(Also, you might want to consider making this an OR query for the terms? So it matches any name, not forced to match all? You can use `$query->orWhere`)

---

**UPDATE**

try it like this:

```
$queryString = $request->input('search',null);
$terms = explode(' ', $queryString);

$products = Product::whereIn('name', $terms)->get();

return $this->sendResponse($products->toArray(), 'Products retrieved successfully');
```

Comment: Followed the instructions & removed name:%3A to search=<search string separated by +>... yielded no result. I think somethin's wrong with the way i'm getting the $product ? Anything that is wrong ?

Comment: @AdrianKarr did you try using: $query->orWhere  because how you have it now, is an AND search, which means ALL the keywords must must match. If you use orWhere(), only one has to match.

Comment: Thank you for the question & suggestion. I tried that as suggested by another gentleman , but it didn't really solve my problem. I finally resolved this by using https://stackoverflow.com/a/63664380/13687099

Comment: That solution you have there is vulnerable to SQL INJECTION, you should never include user input like that.

Comment: Thank you for the help Cyril! Really appreciate this

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get much help around & solved this myself. To the ones who may need this in future:

```
$condition = '';
   $terms = explode(" ",$queryString);
   foreach($terms as $text)  
      {  
           $condition .= "name LIKE '%".($text)."%' OR ";  
      }  
      $condition = substr($condition, 0, -4); 
      $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE " . $condition; 
      $result = DB::select($sql_query);
```

- condition  is going to gather all the conditions to be searched.
- terms  is going to collect all searches from the URL
- text is the invidual items from the array.
- products  is the name of the table.
- use DB; should be initialized if you're in a different namespace.

Comment: Whoever reads this should not use this code, it is vulnerable to SQL INJECTION